# Is it possible for an Indian citizen to travel from Mexico to India (Hyderabad or Bangalore) without requiring a transit visa?

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens, india, transit-visas, mexico

I am an Indian, living in Mexico and want to travel to India, either Hyderabad or Bangalore, without having any transit visa.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

**Yes.** Because [Indian citizens do not need an airport transit visa to transit in the Netherlands](https://www.government.nl/topics/visa-for-the-netherlands-and-the-caribbean-parts-of-the-kingdom/documents/forms/2015/11/26/list-of-airport-transit-visa-countries), a possibility is to transit through Amsterdam (AMS). And indeed looking for Mexico to Hyderabad on [ITA](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/) yields a Mexico-Amsterdam-Mumbai-Hyderbad itinerary with KLM (with the second and third legs operated by Jet Airways).